# Stop event from propagating to another instance of same web component?

Tags: javascript, web-component, native-web-component

I've got a child web component (`exercise-input`) with a custom event that's sending some data over to my parent web component (`muscle-group`) it's nested in. The issue is that when I add additional instances of my parent component to the page, the button in the child component that updates the value in the parent component will update that value on every instance of the parent component.

I used `document.dispatchEvent(numSetsDecrease)` in the child and `document.addEventListener` in the parent - is there something I need to replace "document" with? Do I need to [stop propagation](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/154764/how-do-you-stop-an-application-event-from-propagating-to-another-instance-of-the) somehow?

The child component:

```js
    const exerciseInputTemplate = document.createElement('template');
    exerciseInputTemplate.innerHTML = ` 
    
      <div class="exercises">
        <hr>
        <div class="exerciseSetsRepRange">
          <div class="sideBySide">
              <input type="text" placeholder="Exercise">
              <div class="numSetsBtns">
                <button class="subtractSetBtn">-</button>
                <span class="numSets"></span>
                <button class="addSetBtn">+</button>
              </div>
          </div>
          <div class="sideBySide">
            <input type="number" placeholder="Rep Range Low" min="1">
            <input type="number" placeholder="Rep Range High" min="1">
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    `;
     
    class ExerciseInput extends HTMLElement {
     constructor() {
       super(); 
       this.attachShadow({ mode: 'open'});
       this.shadowRoot.appendChild(exerciseInputTemplate.content.cloneNode(true));
     }
    
      connectedCallback() {
        const subtractSetBtn = this.shadowRoot.querySelector('.subtractSetBtn');
        const numSets = this.shadowRoot.querySelector('.numSets');
        const addSetBtn = this.shadowRoot.querySelector('.addSetBtn');
        numSets.textContent = 3 + ' sets';
    
        // Click listner for subtract set btn with nested custom event
        subtractSetBtn.addEventListener('click', function(event){
          let numSetsInt = parseInt(numSets.textContent);
          numSetsInt -= 1;
          numSets.textContent = numSetsInt + ' sets';
    
          if (parseInt(numSets.textContent) === 0) {
            subtractSetBtn.disabled = true;
          }
    
          // Custom event sending -1 to the parent
          const numSetsDecrease = new CustomEvent('numSetsDecrease', {
            bubbles: false,
            detail: {
              numSetValue: -1
            }
          });
          document.dispatchEvent(numSetsDecrease);
        });
    
        // Click listner for add set btn with nested custom event
        addSetBtn.addEventListener('click', function(event){
          let numSetsInt = parseInt(numSets.textContent);
          numSetsInt += 1;
          numSets.textContent = numSetsInt + ' sets';
    
          if (parseInt(numSets.textContent) > 0) {
            subtractSetBtn.disabled = false;
          }
    
          // Custom event sending +1 to the parent
          const numSetsIncrease = new CustomEvent('numSetsIncrease', {
            bubbles: false,
            detail: {
              numSetValue: 1
            }
          });
          document.dispatchEvent(numSetsIncrease);
        });
      }
    }
   
    window.customElements.define('exercise-input', ExerciseInput);
```

The parent component:

```js
    const muscleGroupTemplate = document.createElement('template');
    muscleGroupTemplate.innerHTML = ` 
      <form class="programBuilder">
        <div class="inputDiv muscleGroupDiv">
          <input id="muscleGroupInput" name="muscleGroupInput" list="muscleGroupsList" placeholder="Muscle Group">
          <datalist id="muscleGroupsList">
          </datalist>
        </div>
    
        <div class="inputDiv setsDiv">
          <label for="setsRange" class="setsValue"></label>
          <input type="range" min="1" max="30" class="setsRange" value="15">
          <p class="numSetsOutput"></p>
        </div>
    
        <exercise-input></exercise-input>
        <exercise-input></exercise-input>
        <exercise-input></exercise-input>
    
        <button class="addExerciseBtn">Add Exercise</button>
      </form>
    `;
     
    class MuscleGroup extends HTMLElement {
      constructor() {
        super();
        this.attachShadow({ mode: 'open'});
        this.shadowRoot.appendChild(muscleGroupTemplate.content.cloneNode(true));
      }
    
      connectedCallback() {
        // Updating the number sets output with data from the child elements
        const numSetsOutput = this.shadowRoot.querySelector('.numSetsOutput');
        numSetsOutput.textContent = '9 total sets';
    
        document.addEventListener('numSetsDecrease', function(event){
          let numSetsOutputValue = parseInt(numSetsOutput.textContent);
          numSetsOutputValue += event.detail.numSetValue;
          numSetsOutput.textContent = `${numSetsOutputValue} total sets`; 
        });
        
        document.addEventListener('numSetsIncrease', function(event){
          let numSetsOutputValue = parseInt(numSetsOutput.textContent);
          numSetsOutputValue += event.detail.numSetValue;
          numSetsOutput.textContent = `${numSetsOutputValue} total sets`;
        });
      }
    }
     
    window.customElements.define('muscle-group', MuscleGroup);
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated! I've been trying to figure this out all day.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An Event **bubbles** up the DOM.

https://javascript.info/bubbling-and-capturing

[image]

`document.addEventListener` captures **all** named Events from its children

Instead you:

- dispatchEvent from your buttons
- The Events need `bubbles:true` **and** `composed:true` to cross shadowRoots
- a Listener at `<muscle-group>` then captures the bubbling Events and processes them
  **it only receives Events from its children!**
- if you do **not** have **nested** groups you don't have use `stopPropagation`, Events bubbling on to `document` do no harm

PS. Your `<exercise-iput>` has 2 buttons which do the same, one adds, one substracts.

The moment you copy/pasted that first button code, a *"This Needs A Component"* alarm should have warned you to create a `<exercise-input-button add="-1">`

Comment: My apologies - I'm new here and figured my question was buried. I definitely won't do that going forward.

Also, thank you so much - it works!

I updated the custom events to include bubbles: true and composed: true, made sure each custom event was dispatched by the corresponding button, then changed the event listener in muscle-group to be attached to "this."

You're right - I'll refactor those two buttons into a new component. Thanks!

Really appreciate the help!

Comment: Then you can mark this answer as the correct one. (and delete that other question) It helps to read the [StackOverflow guide](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) And learning how to [include running code](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) in your questions gets you better answers.